# What type of Schengen visa do I need to visit Germany twice?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I am intending to marry my fiance and I am therefore planning to travel to Germany to visit his family. I am a non-EU citizen and need a visa. The planned travel times will be as following:

- 18th March till 5th of April
- beginning of June till end of June

I know about the documents required and we can arrange those. However, I am still not certain about the visa process. For instance, will I apply at the German Embassy for a short-stay visa for the first journey, and then for a second visa for the second journey as well?

Comment: No you can apply for a multiple entry visa the first time itself. No need to apply twice. Whether you are given a multiple entry visa is a different question, but you should apply for a multiple entry one.

Comment: Your citizenship would help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your country citizenship is not on the list of [Annex II countries](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2001R0539:20110111:EN:HTML), you will need to apply for a short-term multi-entry visa.

You will need to provide the proper documentation to support both trips and request that the visa is issued for a duration that covers both periods of your stay. In the worst case scenario (assuming your documents are in order), the German consulate will issue a single-entry visa for your first trip and afterwards you will have plenty of time to apply for another visa for your second trip.

Also note that once you get married, it will become much easier to apply for EU visas as you will become a [non-EU family member](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm).